# what is the meaning of this sed command: `;/@/{h;s/test/next/g;x;G}`?

Tags: shell, sed, command

```
sed -e 's/72;/72, next_val = 0x11111111;/;/@/{h;s/test/next/g;x;G}'
fmt_vuln.c > fmt_vuln2.c
```

could you tell me about what is the meaning of `;/@/{h;s/test/next/g;x;G}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
;/@/{h;s/test/next/g;x;G}? 

/@/  search for an `@` sign
{}   for the lines where that is true do this 'block' of code
h    put the pattern match in the hold space
s/   substitute test for next everywhere in the space
g    do the previous substitution for all matches on the line
x    swap the hold with the pattern space
G    Add a new line with the contents of the hold space.
```

Comment: totally solved my problem through your answer. thank you ^^

Answer (score 6):

```
/@/ # For pattern-space containing the character @ do the following
{
  h              # place a copy of the pattern-space into the hold-space
  s/test/next/g  # replace all instances of "test" with "next" in the pattern-space
  x              # swap the pattern-space with the hold-space
  G              # append a newline followed by contents of hold-space to the pattern-space
}
```

So, for every line containing a @, the modified version of the pattern-space will be printed followed by the original (the hold-space contains the unmodified version).

see [Command Summary for Sed](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/appa_03.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much :) your answer is really helpful to me. ^^